# Can spock mock dynamic objects

Tags: spring, spock

As you can see, I tried to mock response dynamically.

`underTest.getByTaskIds(taskIds)` will pass a list of `taskIds`, inside the method I will invoke `underTest.getByTaskId(taskId, channelId, false)` separately.
But this won't work.

```
    when:
    def actual = underTest.getByTaskIds(taskIds)

    then:
    taskIds.forEach({ taskId ->
        underTest.getByTaskId(taskId, channelId, false) >> mockResp.get(taskId)
    })
    actual.size() == expectedResultSize

    where:
    taskIds                                             | mockResp     | expectedResultSize
    [] as Set<UUID>                                     | [key: value] | 1
    [UUID.randomUUID()] as Set<UUID>                    | [key: value] | 1
    [UUID.randomUUID(), UUID.randomUUID()] as Set<UUID> | [key: value] | 2
```

## Example

```
    class UnderTest:

        void taskId(id){
            do something
        }

        void taskIds(ids)->
        {
            this.taskId(id)
        }
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. I cannot even see the definition of `underTest` and `mockResp`. Please transform your question into an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which I can analyse and ideally compile + run. I answered two of your previous questions already and you habe 4.5k reputation, so you should know how to ask questions in SO.

Comment: @kriegaex I provided the simple example on my question. Any thought? I think it's simple enough. Spock just doesn't work as it should do

Comment: Thanks, but I said MCVE and not pseudo code. And still where `mockResp` comes from is unclear. Give your questions some more love, the reward will be better (and quicker) answers. Make it as easy as possible for others to understand, analyse and answer your questions. I cannot copy, paste, compile and run incomplete code. Isn't it more complicated to remove method, class, package names and variable definitions instead of just providing something complete?

Comment: @kriegaex, updated the `mockResp` in the example

Comment: `UnderTest` is still pseudo code, has two void methods with undefined argument types, none of them being `getByTaskIds`. Your Spock test is incomplete, the class under test too. Look, you have a reputation of 4.5k and I have to explain 5x what an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is? Do you think I want to beg for information just so as to be able to provide you with an **answer for free?** Don't be so incredibly lazy!